# Jpa запрос с коллекцией в качестве параметра

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa

В общем у меня есть две сущности с двухсторонней связью many to many - Post и Tag. Так же есть метод в рест контроллере, в который приходит массив названий тегов. Мне нужно через JpaRepository найти посты, которые включают в себя все пришедшие с контроллера имена тегов. Тоесть к примеру в запросе теги "java", "jpa" и "spring", результатом должны быть все посты, к которым привязаны ВСЕ эти тэги.
Я пробовала сделать:

```
    @Query("select p from Post p left join p.tags tags where tags.name in ?1")
    List<Post> findByTags(Collection<String> names);
```

Но оно отдает все посты, в которых есть хоть один тег из коллекции параметров.
Вопрос в том, можно ли сделать то, что мне нужно лишь с помощью JPA, или мне нужно самостоятельно отсортировать эти посты?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
@Query("select p from Post p where all(p.tags.name) in ?1")
```

или

```
@Query("select p from Post p where p.tags.name all in ?1")
```

или

```
@Query("select p from Post p left join p.tags tags where tags.name all in ?1")
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает